Why do we pray hands together today
Why as moderate Christian goes we pray hands together, yet before Christ crucified we prayed hands apart?

I do not understand the question. When did people pray with 'hands apart' ? It is wholly natural to clasp the hands together when one pleads or begs for something. We do it to one another and we do it towards God.

Are you in the Roman Catholic faith community? I have seen arguments about that in our diocese a few times over the past decade.

We see Moses praying fervently with hands stretched out in Ex 17:11-12:

As   long as Moses held up his hands, the Israelites were winning, but whenever he lowered his hands, the Amalekites were winning. 12 When Moses’ hands grew tired, they took a stone and put it under him and he sat on it. Aaron and Hur held his hands up—one on one side, one on the other—so that his hands remained steady till sunset.

<  Folded palms look like a heart, therefore, one can be said to be offering one's heart to God in prayer. When a person is praying with folded hands, his/her little finger takes the first position, signifying that  humility gets recognition . Thirdly, it is neither practical nor easy for all the faithful in a church to pray with hands spread out for a considerably long time. Of course, the faithful are encouraged to pray with raised hands on certain occasion s for instance, during the recital of the Lord's Prayer in the Holy Mass. Praying with folded hands is less strenuous individually and more practical in a group.
